# What does it mean by "came to believe"?

Tags: idiom-meaning

I've encountered this expression "came to believe" multiple times, I do know about what "believe" means, but I cannot understand the meaning of "came to". Can you make me understand it?

Comment: _Come to believe_ is an idiom meaning "change one's beliefs" -- _come to_ means _become_, except that _become is used before adjectives (_become sick, become tired_) and _come to_ is used before verbs (_come to believe, come to realize, come to enjoy living here_).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the person's belief arrived over a period of time and not at once, as a revelation.

Consider the following from a book called *[They Came Back](https://books.google.com/books?id=0D9ZUqLFdH8C&pg=PA22&dq=%22came%20to%20believe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwATg8ahUKEwia6tW-u8rHAhWKmoAKHfQWBrU#v=onepage&q=%22came%20to%20believe%22&f=false)* by Charles Raymond Dillon in which he describes the case of a girl named Dorothy Eady in the early years of the previous century:

At age four, Dorothy goes on an outing to the British Museum and is fascinated by the Egyptian Department.  She dreams about Ancient Egypt.  By age seven she can identify the places she sees in her dreams.  And

> By the time she was sixteen Dorothy was spending all her time reading
>   and studying about Ancient Egypt.  She *gradually* **came to believe** that
>   she had been [Pharaoh] Seti's wife or lover in a previous life and had born him a
>   son.

Emphases mine.  So Dorothy's belief in her past life in Egypt arrived piece by piece over more than a decade.  Note the progressive forms of the verbs -- "spending," "reading," "studying" -- that tell of action over an interval.

Answer (score 1):

'to come to ' is not restricted to believing.

**Other examples**

*There is, of course, much that he cannot come to understand by this method.* [Philosophy of Education: Education and human being  By Paul Heywood Hirst, Patricia White](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FB0UAUK1kpIC&pg=PA248&dq=%22come%20to%20understand%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBGoVChMIr66sgrvKxwIV6GvbCh2kPg5A#v=onepage&q=%22come%20to%20understand%22&f=false)

*He came to the conclusion that you are the only one who has understood photography* [How, When, and Why Modern Art Came to New York  By Marius de Zayas, Francis M. Naumann](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qkw7YkOpjfsC&pg=PA177&dq=%22he%20came%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBGoVChMI7MvZrLrKxwIV42jbCh2k-QGy#v=onepage&q=%22he%20came%20to%22&f=false)

*s/he will come to the realisation that thing-ness is illusory* [Perspectival Thinking: For Inquiring Organisations](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yhqQadVbeUoC&pg=PA103&dq=%22will%20come%20to%20the%20realisation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMInIGZw7vKxwIVjI7bCh2MUQ6c#v=onepage&q=%22will%20come%20to%20the%20realisation%22&f=false)

You can see that it is frequently used when describing the completion of a mental process.  I am not entirely in agreement with deadrat because I believe you can come to a realisation instantly, e.g.

*the heart of it came to me in an instant* [The Art And Craft Of Storytelling: A Comprehensive Guide To Classic Writing By Nancy Lamb](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=N2CNIDFTy5oC&pg=PT57&dq=%22came%20to%20me%20in%20an%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAWoVChMI9MTyxrzKxwIVY53bCh3I1AsX#v=onepage&q=%22came%20to%20me%20in%20an%22&f=false)

Finally I should mention that something can *come to be, come to grief, come to pass, come to rest* and so on.

**Answer**

'to come to something' means to leave one  state of understanding or being and arrive at a new state.

Comment: "It came to me in an instant" is not equivalent usage to "I came to believe." "I came to believe" or "I came to understand" definitely connotes something that happens over time.

Comment: @barbecue - Well, we're trading opinions now. Can you substantiate that with examples? Btw, I didn't claim it was *always* instantaneous.

Comment: My main point was that "It came to me" and "I came to" are completely different idioms.

Comment: The phrase "come to" has a lot of meanings, but in the specific example the OP is using, I've never seen it mean an instantaneous revelation, it has always meant a change taking place over time, usually as a result of acquiring new knowledge or wisdom. E.g. "Over the years, I came to understand what my father really meant."